# Why sometimes props not equals state in my case?

Tags: reactjs

I have following react code (it's not my own component).

In render method sometimes `this.props.src != this.state.src`
I can't understand why this happened.

Also I think `state.src` is not necessary, `props.src enough`.

```js
export default class ImageBlock extends PureComponent {
    _b = _b('image')
    isMount = true
    state = {
        src: this.props.src,
        failed: false
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const image = new Image()
        image.src = this.state.src

        image.onerror = () => {
            if (this.isMount) {
                this.setState({ failed: true })
            }
        }
     }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.isMount = false
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.src !== this.state.src) {
           console.log('Sometimes this condition is true')
         }

         return (
             <div className={ this._b({ failed: this.state.failed 
             }).mix(this.props.className) }>
             {this.state.failed ? (
                <div className={ this._b('img', { failed: true }) }>
                  <NoImageIcon className={ this._b('icon') } />
                </div>
             ) : (
                <img
                  className={ 
                  this._b('img').mix(this.props.imageClassName) }
                  src={ this.state.src }
                  alt={ this.props.title }
             />
             )}
            </div>
         )
   }
}
```

How I use this component:

I use it in function:

```js
publisher_applications = (el, idx, index) => (
<li ref={ index } key={ idx } className={ bemCn('results-item') }>
  <SearchItem
    className={ bemCn('results-link', { selected: index === 
    this.state.selected }) }
    index={ index }
    onClick={ this.handleClick }
    onMouseEnter={ this.handleMouseenter }
    to={{ pathname: paths.application(el.id), query: this.getQuery(el) 
    }}
  >
    <div className={ bemCn('results-image') }>
      <ImageBlock
        src={ setImageSize({
          url: el.application.icon_url,
          platform: el.platform.name.toLowerCase(),
          size: 24
        }) }
      />
    </div>
    <div className={ bemCn('results-info') }>
      <div className={ bemCn('results-name') }>{el.application.name} 
      </div>
      <div className={ bemCn('results-author') }>{el.publisher.name} 
      </div>
    </div>
    <Icon
      icon={ el.platform.name.toLowerCase() === 'android' ? 
      googleplayIcon : appstoreIcon }
      className={ bemCn('results-type') }
    />
  </SearchItem>
</li>
 )
```

which execute it in:

```js
  renderResults = () => {
let index = 1
const { withoutTitle, isLanding } = this.props

return this.props.keys.map(
  (key, i) => {

   return (this.props.results[key] ? (
      <div key={key} className={bemCn('category')}>
        {!withoutTitle && <div className={bemCn('category-title')}> 
        {TITLES[key]}</div>}
        <ul className={bemCn('results-list')}>
          {this.props.results[key].slice(0, 
         SEARCH_RESULTS_LIMIT).map((k, idx) => {
            if (isLanding && key !== 'application') return null

            const item = this[key](k, idx, index)

            index++

            return item
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ) : null)
  }
)
}
```

here one of `this.key` is method `publisher_applications.`

I get from server `this.props.result`.

Comment: I think you're right. `this.props.src` should be enough. The `componentWillMount` logic will not run again if the `src` prop changes though, but it doesn't do that currently  either.

Comment: @Tholle, what do you think, why sometimes this.props.src != this.state.src ? It's magic for me

Comment: It depends on how you use your `ImageBlock` component. Maybe you change the `src` prop when using it?

Comment: @Tholle I show image in loop with different src

Comment: If you log `this.state.src` and `this.props.src` inside `if (this.props.src !== this.state.src) { ... }`, what does it say?

Comment: @Tholle different value, but it happened about 1 of 20 times (src I get from server). In construct we do this.state.src = this.props.src, but how can it differ

Comment: It differs because of what is passed to it as props. You didn't post the code showing what's passed to it, so we can't help with anything here

Comment: @LadyBird I have updated my post

Comment: I dont know why this is happening, but I agree with "this.props.src is enough." I dont see why you would need to keep the src internally as state if it is being controlled externally. Still though I'm curious as to what's causing this.